# Internet Explorer does not execute ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my ajax call. Every browser I tested executes my ajax call (Chrome, Firefox) but IE won't and I don't know why. Can you help me?

```
    function getAjaxStatus(url, callback) {
    var id = $.urlParam(url, 'serverid');
    console.log(url);
    if (!serverControl[url] || typeof serverControl[url] === 'undefined') {

        serverControl[url] = 1;
        $.ajax({
            //cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (model) {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback(model, id);
                }
            },
            error: function (errorMsg) {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback(errorMsg, id);
                }
            }                
        })
        .always(function () {
            serverControl[url] = 0;
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the call isn't being made, or is the call failing? What event is this code run under? What are the values of `callback`, `model` and `id`? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: `error` does not return simply an error message, but a `jqXHR` object, the `textStatus`, and `errorThrown`. Also, it's strange that you use `always` next to `success` and `error`. The two latter are deprecated. Use `done()` and `fail()` instead. Finally, what is callback. Try doing a simple console log to see if your ajax succeeds or fails.

Comment: console log gets me this error https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/8t19bkk9(v=vs.94).aspx right before the }) close tag of the ajax call

Comment: tried deleting the , in the line before it. Then I get a new error (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/8t19bkk9(v=vs.94).aspx on var server = document.querySelectorAll('.js-server'); located in another function)

Comment: excuse me. This is the error I get: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn720784(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: In which version of IE do you get this error? Note that `querySelectorAll` is not supported in older version of IE. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: I'm using Version 11.0.... so it should be supported.

Comment: I think it did not work because of the compatibility mode for intranet-sites. Managed to get it working without using querySelectorAll. Thank you =)